# What does "No need to email yet in between" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Having a conversation with a native speaker by sms service, I am having difficulty to understand what it means exactly when someone says "no need to email yet in between" in the following context (me, as the actor A and the native, as the actor B):

> A: Please just use this sms service for our important issues, and send email for our general communication.
>
> B: Let's use this sms service for our important issues. **No need to email yet in between.**

Does that mean that I am expected to send just emails instead of sms service?

Comment: It was just a conversation (me as the actor "A") with a native (the actor "B"), which makes me confused. Does it mean that the native asked me not to use email to communicate?

Comment: I am sure that the native english speaker didn't mean to write 'yet in between' but I am struggling to think how SMS spell-checking could come up with this.

Comment: Perhaps the native doesnt want such a small conversation (communication by email in this context), which is offered by A. So, my conclusion is: B wants to communicate (with A) only for significant (important) issues by text message service. No email needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I interpret the conversation:

> You: I will send you SMS messages for important things, and emails for other (not-important) things
>
> Native: Just send me SMS messages for important things. You do not need to email me for not-important things at this time.

To see how I came to this conclusion, I'll break up the native's message.

> Let's use this sms service for our important issues.

This part is pretty clear: for important things, use the sms service.

> No need to email

"You do not need to email me" or "Please do not email me"

> In between

Between what? I assume he means "in between the sms messages you send me"

> yet

"at this time", so maybe as the project develops this will change and you should email him. But for now, you do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning is:

> B: Let's use this sms service for our important issues. No need to email yet **at the same time**.

or

> B: Let's use this sms service for our important issues. No need to email yet **in the meantime**.

See [***in between***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/in-between):

> 2) in the midst of

and [***meantime***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/meantime) synonyms:

> at the same time, concurrently